# Map reduce key, value pairs

Tags: mapreduce

Please help me to find the map and reduce functions for the following question.

I have multiple log files with IP addresses and error codes. I want as output the IP address, errorcode and how may time the error code appears for that IP address. I only want the key value pairs not the code.

Please give me the: map input "key, value" and output "key,value" and the reduce input"key,value" and output "key,value".

I have right now the map input "logfile,textline" and output "ipadress, numberOffErrorCodes", "numberOffErrorCodes, errorCode".

But I don't know how i must continue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.  One is to use the identity mapper.  This will collect all error codes for a given IP address in the reducer.  You'd then create a map of error codes to counts (say map) and then the reducer could emit one line for each code in the map.

Another option is to create a key from the ip address and the error code.  For example, 123.44.55.66:18 (18 is the error code).  Then the reducer could strip off the ':NN' and you could simply count the number of entries.